crear un archivo txt y permitirle al usuario guardarlo en cuelquier lugar C#
Les explico, estoy tratando de guardar un archivo en una ubicación y nombre que el usuario quiera.
De momento lo guardo en el directorio del mismo sistema. Uso este código:
string rutafija = @"Works\Trabajo.txt";

if (!Directory.Exists(@"Works")) { Directory.CreateDirectory(@"Works"); }

StreamWriter trabajo = new StreamWriter(rutafija);
trabajo.WriteLine(txtRutaSistema.Text);
trabajo.WriteLine(txtRutaBackup.Text);
trabajo.WriteLine(txtBD.Text);
trabajo.WriteLine(nudMeces.Value);
trabajo.WriteLine(nudDias.Value);

if (cbTareaAuto.Checked == true)
{
    trabajo.WriteLine(dtpHoraBackup.Text);
}

trabajo.Close();


Que leas el [tour] nuevamente, porque las preguntas que preguntan sobre recomendaciones terminan cerradas... no se que esperas que se te recomiende, si queres guardarlo en el lugar que quiera el usuario, o le abris el explorador de carpetas para que seleccione el lugar, o le pedis la ruta... no se que esperas que te recomienden...

@gbianchi el "Que me recomiendan" solo fue un error, eso lo voy a eliminar ya que me lo señalas, lo que pasa es que hice la misma pregunta en otro foro y no tienen problemas con eso, solo hice un copiar y pegar para ahorrarme tiempo. En fin, estoy buscando que me digan cual es la opción para obtener la ruta que me da el usuario y sumarle el nombre que el decida ponerle.

Esto no es un foro ;) esto es un sitio de preguntas y respuestas concretas a problemas concretos.. cual es el problema al pedir la ruta por consola????

o es una aplicacion visual?? o sea.. cual es el problema que tuviste para pedir la ruta???

@PandaCodes Para concatenar variables se usa +... Ejemplo "Juan" + " " + "Perez"... Ante cualquier problema simple de programación que tengas, le podrías preguntar a https://chatgpt.com en caso que el bot no te diera tales respuestas podrías volver aquí a este sitio.

@gbianchi si, una visual. y si, disculpa por la estructura de la pregunta. pero nada, la prox la elaboro mejor.

@PandaCodes Es que NO has formulado pregunta alguna, yo creo que tu pregunta es ¿Como levantar la ventana de dialogo para la selección de carpetas en _____(ingresar el tipo de aplicación: winforms, wpf, maui, etc) ? Pero es una suposición. Debes [edit] tu pregunta y agregar LA PREGUNTA y el tipo de proyecto que estas usando

Todas esas tecnologias que nombra Yussef, tienen un objeto que te abre un selector de carpetas o archivos donde el usuario podria seleccionar donde guardarlo y hasta el nombre... por eso, sigue sin ser una pregunta con mucho sentido...

Una manera de pedirle datos al usuario es con Console.ReadLine.
Console.WriteLine("Ruta:");
string ruta = Console.ReadLine();

Otra forma es que salga el cuadro de guardar SaveFileDialog.
private void boton_guardar_click(object enviador, EventArgs e){
    using (SaveFileDialog dialogo_guardar_archivo = new SaveFileDialog()){
        dialogo_guardar_archivo.Filter = "Archivos de texto (*.txt)|*.txt|Todos los archivos (*.*)|*.*";
        dialogo_guardar_archivo.Title = "Guardar Archivo";
        if (dialogo_guardar_archivo.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK){
            string ruta_archivo = dialogo_guardar_archivo.FileName;
            string contenido_archivo = "Contenido del archivo.";
            using (StreamWriter escritor = new StreamWriter(ruta_archivo)){
                escritor.WriteLine(contenido_archivo);
            }
        }
    }
}

Me alegro hablar español, porque así puedo diferenciar qué palabras son de C# y cuáles son las variables.
Adapta el código a conveniencia.
